# Behaviours of Arrays.binarySearch

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

My intention is to skip some predefined rows while looping through an excel file as shown below:

```
int rowIndex = 0;
int[] rowsToBeSkipped = new int[]{1,2,15,16,17,18,31,32,33,34};

while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
{
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    if(Arrays.binarySearch(rowsToBeSkipped, rowIndex) == -1){
        System.out.println("true "+rowIndex);
    }else{
        System.out.println("false "+rowIndex);
    }
        rowIndex++;
    }
}
```

And below is the result:

```
true 0
false 1
false 2
false 3
false 4
false 5
false 6
false 7
false 8
false 9
false 10
false 11
false 12
false 13
false 14
false 15
false 16
false 17
false 18
false 19
false 20
false 21
false 22
false 23
false 24
false 25
false 26
false 27
false 28
false 29
false 30
false 31
false 32
false 33
false 34
false 35
false 36
false 37
false 38
false 39
false 40
false 41
```

Can anyone explain why only 0 can match the condition?

Comment: try using HashMap<Integer,String> map instead of array and add map values like map.put(1,true) , .... and so on .... and in while loop check condition like map.getKey(rowIndex)!=null..... it will efficient when compared to binary search on array.....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are misusing this method. Quoting its documentation (emphasis mine):

> Returns:
>      index of the search key, if it is contained in the array; **otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1). The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the array**

Which means that this method would return -1 if and only if the value you are trying to search would be inserted at the start of the array -- which is the case of 0 here.

You should test for any value strictly less than 0, not just -1:

```
if (Arrays.binarySearch(rowsToBeSkipped, rowIndex) < 0) {
    // etc
```